# The correct way to manage data for display in the YII framework?

Tags: yii

If I have a shop that displays a bunch of products and I get these products returned from the database as an array, is there a specific way that you can display this data using YII templates or is it sufficient to simply loop through the array and print it out in "divs" as needed?

I know if I just spit it out in DIVs, it would work, but is it the "correct" way to do it according to the framework?

Comment: do you have any specific requirement for how the view should look?

Comment: It would be a grid of products? Like you would see on a typical store frontend? My concern is going off on a tangent, only to find out YII has some way to manage templates in a "Smarty" kind of way?

Comment: ok, have you tried any of the zii widgets?

Comment: I will investigate quick, but would that be something to use in a similar way as Wordpress Display Widgets? Or Drupal Blocks?

Comment: sorry got no idea about those, and how they work. zii gives you pagination, sorting, and custom styling though

Comment: Just confirming, but I think "zii widgets" was in a nutshell exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: no problem, added an answer, with a few more helpful links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this there are [zii widgets](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/extension.use#zii-extensions), and also [many extensions](http://www.yiiframework.com/extensions/?category=15).

I think for a store [CListView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CListView) will be a good start. There are [many wikis](http://www.yiiframework.com/search/?q=clistview&lang=en&type=wiki) that explain a lot about CListView.

You can easily extend it and add functionality.

Zii widgets provide pagination, sorting, and custom styling too, when used alongwith a [data provider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDataProvider).

Comment: I am able to convert an array to a dataprovider, but I'm still stuck on placing four elements (image, price, description) into one div, instead of one line in columns. But thanks! This put me in the right direction..

Comment: css is your friend for such things :)

Comment: But it spits it out as a table? How can I spit it out as DIVs ?

Comment: shot. Thanks! This also helped a lot --> http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/tumblr-data-provider/